# Orchard 1.7.2 Custom Forms does not save data

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I openend a fresh Orchard 1.7.2 website using WebMatrix and created a few simple forms using the **Custom Forms** module.

I am using SQL Server as the database.

My issue is, I am unable to save any data from the website.
In the Admin pages, there is a new item saved and shows the creation time but there is no form data which I typed in.

When I save any form, by clicking on Submit button, it does not throw any error. I checked the logs as well and nothing in there.

*However, once I login and from Admin dashboard go to "New" and then try to save a form, it is saved perfectly fine.*

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Please file a bug with precise repro steps.

Comment: For the time being, I moved back to Orchard 1.7.1 and this solves my issue. Indeed a bug in 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go there: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20318 for discussion.
I think they fixed it in 30c43ad130dc09dd62563470fb8c0aa11e5dae4b changeset, you can see changes here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/30c43ad130dc09dd62563470fb8c0aa11e5dae4b

Download the latest source and open the solution with visual studio and compile the CustomForms Module Project(On Release) and then replace its assembly with the buggy one and also don't forget to Recycle the App Pool.

Comment: If you are using raw source code & Visual Studio, I have to remind you that when you make these changes to CustomForms module, you need to clean/rebuild that module before starting the app again and testing.